# Apache Tika: docx files parsing via Rest in java

Tags: java, rest, apache-tika, tika-server

I'm using Appache Tika in server mode.
I need to develop java rest client for parsing files.
For pdf file upload i'm using code:

```
fileBody = new FileBody(file, "application/pdf");
multiPartEntity.addPart("uploaded_file", fileBody);
pdfPutRequest.setEntity(multiPartEntity);
response = client.execute(pdfPutRequest);
```

Using apache.http library. 
Now i try to develop docx part, but i don't know which mimeType i need to provide (application/docx give me the error).
Without mimeTipe i receive the exception " Unsupported Media Type" in the Tika server.
So which type i need to provide and do i need to do some other changes.

Solved!

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution:

```
HttpPost docxPutRequest new HttpPost(url);
docxPutRequest.setHeader("Accept", "text/plain");
MultipartEntity multiPartEntity = new MultipartEntity();
FileBody fileBody = new FileBody(file);
multiPartEntity.addPart("uploaded_file", fileBody);
docxPutRequest.setEntity(multiPartEntity);
response = client.execute(docxPutRequest);
```

May be this will help to someone

Answer (score 0):

The official mime type for `.docx` files is

```
application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document
```

If you use the Tika CLI tool in `--detect` mode it can tell you that

Alternately, the Tika Server has a detection mode available [as documented in the Tika Server wiki](https://wiki.apache.org/tika/TikaJAXRS#Detector_Resource).

Finally, Tika will auto-detect the mime type for you if none is given, see [the text extraction part of the Tika Server docs](https://wiki.apache.org/tika/TikaJAXRS#Get_the_Text_of_a_Document) for info on giving or not giving a mimetype hint with your file

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I already see the detect option, and tried it.  I found the problem in other place... when i sent the file, i used multi part, but done this via PUT request... now i see that in documentation it supposed to sent via POST...